# Qt multiple QSlider control at same time

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have two QSlider widgets at same window. I cannot control both of them with my two fingers at the same time.

For example, one of sliders is used for throttle and other is used for steering in a car game.

How can I handle this ?

Comment: `QTouchEvent` is what you are looking for. I am not sure if `QSlider`s are implemented to handle this kind of events, but you can start by allowing your `QSlider` to receive touch events using `ui->slider1->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents); ui->slider2->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);`.

Comment: If that does not work for you, then you need to subclass `QSlider`, override `event()`, and handle touch events (`QEvent::TouchBegin`, `QEvent::TouchUpdate`, `QEvent::TouchEnd`, `QEvent::TouchCancel`) yourself. You may be handling them by sending corresponding mouse click events.

Comment: I saw QTouchEvent but I think problem is different. When I press second slider while pressing first slider, second slider doesn't change its value, it behaves like stucked or freezed.

Comment: When taking input from a traditional mouse/keyboard, only one widget can have focus at a time. That's why in your case, only one slider can move at a time. Take a look at [`QTouchEvent` caveats](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html#caveats): "*enabling touch events means multiple widgets can be receiving touch events simultaneously.  For example, it is possible that the user is moving a QSlider with one finger and pressing a QPushButton with another. The signals emitted by these widgets will be interleaved.*". Isn't that exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: Have you tried enabling `Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents` attribute as I said in my first comment?

Comment: I didn't tried but I will try at monday and inform you

Comment: I tried it, it worked. QSlider receive touch events concurrently but it isn't implemented itself so I implemented how to react to touch events.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. According to the [docs here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtouchevent.html#mouse-events-and-touch-event-synthesizing), All touch events that are not accepted by the application get translated to left button mouse events by default. It is odd that you had to re-implement handling touch events. P.S. I don't have a touch screen to test on.

Comment: If you have time, maybe you can add an answer to this question. I am curious on how exactly did you implement handling touch events. . .